# Trigger animation on props with styled components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am trying to run an animation on one of my components when one of the props is equal to true. However, I am getting an error that 'flash is not a function'.

https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-moser-tet99?file=/src/App.js:0-606

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styled, {keyframes} from "styled-components";

const flash = keyframes`
  from {
      opacity: 0;
      }

      to {
      opacity: 1;
      }
`;

const StyledTile = styled.div`
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: pink;
    animation: ${props => props.animate ? flash `0.3s linear 3` : `null`};
`

export default function App() {

  const [doAnimate, setDoAnimate] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <StyledTile animate = {doAnimate}/>
      <button onClick = {() => setDoAnimate(true)}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: The URL in your description points to an empty sandbox.

Comment: Sorry forgot to save it, is it ok now?

Comment: Yes, works now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I used the css helper as the docs states [here](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#keyframes).

```
const StyledTile = styled.div`
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: pink;
  animation: ${props =>
    props.animate &&
    css`
      ${flash} 0.3s linear 3
    `};
`;
```

And here's the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-drake-8qksv?file=/src/App.js:205-387)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the syntax you're using is not supported by `styled-components`, check [this link](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics) out:

> Keyframes are lazily injected when they're used, which is how they can
> be code-splitted, so you have to use [the css helper](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#css) for shared style
> fragments

Here's a working [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-elion-1o3jz?file=/src/App.js). So I had to wrap the animation in that css helper.